# DexGuard with applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dexguard

DexGuard recently switched to a license system with only 1 license per application. This caused this issue when I'm using `applicationIdSuffix` for other buildtypes:

> The package name from the AndroidManifest.xml file
>   [com.example.myapp.debug] doesn't match the package name
>   [com.example.myapp] from your DexGuard license
>   [path/to/dexguard-license.txt]

Is there a workaround or option available this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, eventually GuardSquare updated our license so we could use '.debug' applicationIdSuffix with the same license. As Gabriele suggests in the answers, you could just turn DexGuard off or buy a second license.

Answer (score 1):

> The package name from the AndroidManifest.xml file [com.example.myapp.debug] doesn't match the package name [com.example.myapp] from your DexGuard license [path/to/dexguard-license.txt]

It means that you can use DexGuard only for the package name `com.example.myapp` and you can't use it for the package `com.example.myapp.debug`.

You can:

- buy a second license for the other package
- disable DexGuard for the debug build type

For the second option:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            //nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: We've mailed GuardSquare, the company behind DexGuard, about this and they were able to add a suffix to the license. But I'm curious about your second option, disabling dexguard for the debug build. Is this possible?

Comment: @dumazy Updated the answer.

Comment: okay, I'm having a different issue with this concerning Fabric. To upload obfuscation files to Fabric/Crashlytics, you need to apply the Dexguard plugin before the Fabric plugin. But then Fabric will try crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug and crash because of "Task with path 'dexguardDebug' not found in project"

Comment: No problem. This is a different issue. Thanks for your answer.